# iOS snapshot API unexpected behavioral change

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to take a screenshot and convert it into an image. The screenshot should include the keyboard, if the keyboard is shown.

I have the following minimal reproducible code.

The basic logic is, when user tap on the button, I take the screenshot, and make it half the size, and put it on the top left corner.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
  func takeSnapshot() -> UIView {
    let screen = UIScreen.main
    
    let snapshot = screen.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, screen.scale)
    
    snapshot.drawHierarchy(in: snapshot.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width/2, height: view.frame.height/2))
    imageView.image = image

    return imageView
    
  }
  
  @objc func buttonPressed() {
    let snapshot = takeSnapshot()
    view.addSubview(snapshot)
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
      snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    textField.backgroundColor = .red
    textField.text = "Text Field"
    view.addSubview(textField)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))
    button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
  }
}
```

This is the result on iOS 16. It works perfectly - the screenshot on top left corner has the keyboard.

[image]

However, on iOS 17, as you can see, the screenshot on the top left corner has no keyboard there!

[image]

Edit:
Here's the interface debugger for iOS 16:

[image]

And for iOS 17:

[image]

As you can see, they are both using the separate scene for the keyboard. But they are also slight different. Not sure if it's related to different scenes?

Comment: You should log beta feedback with Apple

Comment: @Paulw11 well maybe it's not a bug, but by design? I am hoping to get some alternatives here.

Comment: You should still log feedback. A behaviour change like this is probably a bug

Comment: @Paulw11 I also added the interface debugger screenshot. I have a feeling that this is related to keyboard belonging to different "Scene"s, but im not too sure.

Comment: It could be. It could be that capturing the keyboard wasn't considered part of the functionality or it could be an unintentional change as the result of apple changing the way the keyboard is rendered into the view hierarchy. They may even consider the original behaviour of capturing the keyboard as unintentional and not desirable.  Log it. The result may be a bug fix or a documentation change noting the difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [WWDC 2023/10281 Keep up with the keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10281), Apple states that the keyboard has been moved out of process in iOS 17. Its view is no longer part of your app. This, presumably, explains why it is not captured.

Comment: Does it mean that it's impossible to capture the keyboard?

Comment: I haven’t watched the full video (found it via a Google search) but I would expect that yes, it is impossible to capture the keyboard in code on iOS 17 and later.